# Run cron every 7am at weekdays not working

Tags: cron

I've cron schedule to send an email every 7am at weekdays with cron expression like this:

```
0 7 * * 1-5
```

i've checked the expression in [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_7_*_*_1-5) and the description seems ok and valid, but the cron won't run at all, i tried to set the cron schedule to run every minutes 30 and its working fine

```
30 * * * 1-5
```

Comment: That *should* work, leading me to believe you have a *different* issue other than `crontab` time specification (hence we need more information). BTW, your second one runs every *hour* on the half-hour (10:30, 11:30, 12:30, etc), just thought I'd clarify that.